# Silverlight 4 & WCF Deseralizing Issue- There was an error deserializing the object of type 'T'. Unexpected end of file

Tags: silverlight, wcf, deserialization

I have come across a large issue that i am having that has suddenly come to light when i upgraded my Silverlight & Web Projects to versions 4 respectively.

Since doing this, all my WCF Services are Failing with the following Error message:

**There was an error deserializing the object of type Anyboat.Admin.UserService.User. Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: LastName, AuthenticateUserResult, AuthenticateUserResponse, Body, Envelope.**

The StackTrace is:

```
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at Anyboat.Admin.UserService.UserServiceClient.UserServiceClientChannel.EndAuthenticateUser(IAsyncResult result)
   at Anyboat.Admin.UserService.UserServiceClient.Anyboat.Admin.UserService.UserService.EndAuthenticateUser(IAsyncResult result)
   at Anyboat.Admin.UserService.UserServiceClient.OnEndAuthenticateUser(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

I put a breakpoint in my SilverlightFaultBehaviour on the Response Message and this is the Envelope reponse i got back. Notice the Carriage return which is between ***"\r\n"*

```
"<s:Envelope xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\r\n  <s:Header>\r\n    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">urn:UserService/AuthenticateUserResponse</a:Action>\r\n    <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:07cc1361-c74c-4449-b423-e982d2ac8e05</a:RelatesTo>\r\n  </s:Header>\r\n  <s:Body>\r\n    <AuthenticateUserResponse>\r\n      <AuthenticateUserResult xmlns:d4p1=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnyBoat.Web.Classes.DataObjects\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\r\n        <d4p1:Active>true</d4p1:Active>\r\n        <d4p1:EmailAddress>robbie@robbietapping.com.au</d4p1:EmailAddress>\r\n        <d4p1:FirstName>Robbie</d4p1:FirstName>\r\n        <d4p1:IsAdministrator i:nil=\"true\" />\r\n        <d4p1:LastName>Tapping</d4p1:LastName>\r\n        <d4p1:Password>xxxxxxxxx</d4p1:Password>\r\n        <d4p1:UserID>2</d4p1:UserID>\r\n        <d4p1:UserName>robbietapping</d4p1:UserName>\r\n      </AuthenticateUserResult>\r\n    </AuthenticateUserR
esponse>\r\n  </s:Body>\r\n</s:Envelope>"
```

Can anyone tell me if there is away around this at all, i upgraded my VS2010 to SP1 where this has started to show itself.

Any Information or answers would be greatfully appreciated.

Thanks

***EDIT***

The Code that the Error Occurs on is:

```
 public Anyboat.Admin.UserService.User EndAuthenticateUser(System.IAsyncResult result) {
                object[] _args = new object[0];
                Anyboat.Admin.UserService.User _result = ((Anyboat.Admin.UserService.User)(base.EndInvoke("AuthenticateUser", _args, result)));
                return _result;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which serialization type do you use at services side? I'm pretty sure that you use some custom serialization. **"\r\n"** problem is pretty common and it occurs when you're trying to deserialize not well formed xml received from service.
So I see two ways:

1. The most preferable way. Check the serializer at service side. It's obvious that service returns xml in wrong format.
2. Add [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) to client and remove special symbols from response before deserialization.

Comment: Thanks for this. this helped me out, it worked out being that the problem was something to do with the Object being transferred over a CustomBindingBehaviour, so i used a basicHttpBinding behaviour instead and that fixed it.